# How can be define the key shortcut to save a project in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, key-bindings

What is the keybinding command to save the current a project in Sublime Text 3? As shown in the image.

I've tried this one, but it doesn't appear as shortcut inside the menu.

```
{"keys": ["ctrl+alt+s"], "command": "save_project_as"}
```

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{"keys": ["ctrl+alt+s"], "command": "save_project_and_workspace_as"}
```

---

### More Info

There's no key binding for that by default (as you've noticed), but the command you want is `save_project_and_workspace_as`.

The easiest way to see what any menu, command palette entry or key binding is doing is to open the Sublime console with <kbd>Ctrl+`</kbd> or `View > Show Console` from the menu and then enter the command:

```python
sublime.log_commands(True)
```

Once you've done that, take an action (e.g. select the menu item) and the console will tell you what command it ran and what arguments it takes.

Comment: As usual, a great and informative post by @OdatNurd